# Translate a loop in C with arrays to MIPS by using the stack

Tags: c, mips, translation

I have a doubt on one exercise that my professor did during a seminar. It's basically a translation from C to MIPS. The C code is as follows:

```
void subr1(char *a, int v[]) {
   int i;
   char c[12];
   for (i=11; i >= 0; i--) {
     v[i] = subr2(c[i], *a);
  }
}
```

And the translation of my professor was the following (I've written comments about what each instruction does and what I don't understand):

```
addiu $sp,$sp,-28 #Activation block
sw $ra, 24($sp) #Space for $ra (4 bytes)
sw $s0, 20($sp) #Space for *a (32-bit address = 4 bytes)
sw $s1, 16($sp) #Space for c (Q1: Shouldn't this be 12 bytes? c is an array of 12 chars = 12*1Byte=12Bytes)
sw $s2 12($sp) #Space for i (4 bytes)
(Q2: Why is he stopping at 12? Doesn't he need to save space for int v[]?)

move $s0,$a0 #Save 'a' in stack
move $s1,$a1 #Save 'c' in stack
li $s2, 11 #i=11

For:
blt $s2, $zero, End #if i<0, then go to 'End'
addu $t0, $s2, $sp (Q3: I'm not sure, but I think he's trying to access v[i] by summing $sp and 'i'. Can you do that, without initialising any register at the beginning like we did for $s0 and $s1?)
lb $a0, 0($t0) #$a0 = v[i] (Q4: Isn't this wrong? It should access c[i], not v[i])
lb $a1, 0($s0) #$a1 = *a
jal sub2 #Jump to sub2
sll $t1, $s2, 2 #$t1 = 4*i
addu $t1,$t1,$sp #$t1 = 4*i + $sp (By this, I guess he's accessing v[i])
sw $v0,0($t1) #v[i] = $v0 (returned value from sub2)
addiu $s2, $s2, -1 #i--
b For

end:
#Close the activation block
lw $s2,12($sp)
lw $s1,16($sp)
lw $s0,20($sp)
lw $ra,24($sp)
addiu $sp,$sp,28
jr $ra #Jump to register address
```

Could somebody help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: v needs no allocation here; it is already allocated and v is the pointer to it.

Comment: The behavior of the C-code is undefined because it uses the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate. *Any* assembly (or none) is conforming as far as the C standard is concerned.